# Ruby REST client publish-subscribe communication possible or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, faye

I am aware of rails REST interface which allow me to access sources. 
and I am aware of publish-subscribe strategy for message passing

Is it possible to implement REST client(not browser but ruby client works on arduino device) to access resource if resource (ex. server informed client that resource is now available you can receive) available via publish subscribe strategy ?

I am aware of [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/). is it possible to implement REST client using Faye to receive via publish-subscribe for ruby ? If it is not possible with Faye which can be other solution for Ruby REST client to build a publish subscribe communication ? How can Faye inform ruby client for resource notification ?

Comment: IMHO you are mixing two irrelevant concepts. REST allow you to access sources and PubSub is a messaging system. You could use REST as a layer for your PubSub to access/search for relevant messages though.

Comment: That is what I exactly need "You could use REST as a layer for your PubSub to access/search for relevant messages though". But what approach should I follow ? can you please suggest me using ruby

Comment: Sorry but you have to reformulate your statement and make it a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is based on HTTP, so it is Request-Response.
you can't make Pub/Sub service with REST.

If I were you, I would use Faye to notify client about new resources, or whatever you want to monitor.

And after notification you can make Ajax request to REST and get new record for example.

But the best approach is to use Faye for pushing changes to client.

Don't be aware, it is quite simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me little bit more how Faye can inform a notification to ruby client ? If possible please give me some steps.

Comment: It is to broad topic for SO. Just check out this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Comment: I watched this railscast where a browser client is created for a particular channel.

Comment: So, the server will notify client via Faye. You have just to implement it. I can't provide you real code, because I don't know anything about your app.

Comment: I watched this railscast where a browser client is created using Javascript but I need to create a ruby client without browser for a particular channel. I understand this railscast. but as you mentioned earlier "I would use Faye to notify client about new resources, or whatever you want to monitor" - how could you send this notification ? can you please describe

Comment: So you would like to receive data not in browser?
Than it makes sense to use some message queue(ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ). Faye it mostly for browser notifications.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply. yes I don't need to use in browser but ruby client will works in the devices(arduino) where browser is not available.  I know how Rabbitmq works. but I don't want to use this middle layer. I have one more question, I don't know much about ruby Eventmachine. Is it possible to apply ruby eventmachine or any other solution without this middle layer to send notification to this device from http serer?

Comment: Well, http server can't send data without request.
And eventmachine is a framework for network apps. It does not give you any message push functionality.

Try zeromq, it is really little and simple library. I'm sure it will satisfy you.